# Calculating the average in java

Tags: java, for-loop, average

```
double Hg = Double.parseDouble(values2[17]);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    double Avg = (Hg + Hg + Hg) / 3;
    System.out.println(Avg);
}
```

My program reads a file and puts everything in a String array called values2. The array element #17 (values2[17]) contains the values I need. I converted that array element into a double so I could then calculate the average. The program should take the first 3 values that are in values[17] and then divide by 3 to calculate the average, but it is just printing out the same values 3 times instead of adding and then dividing.
Any thoughts of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not changing the value you're trying to average?

Comment: Wait, so what exactly is in `values2[17]`? A string of doubles?

Comment: Your logic is `3x/3` which is `x`, so you might as well just print `Hg`

Comment: `(Hg + Hg + Hg) / 3` == `Hg`

Comment: (Hg + Hg + Hg) / 3 = Hg. Not really surprising.

Comment: "first 3 values that are in values[17]", what does that mean exactly. Does values2[17] contain more than 1 value somehow?

Comment: values2[17] contains one value, but my file has more than one line so when it goes to the next line values2[17] is a different number.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're doing (comma seperated String of values), it could be as simple as...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] values = new String[18];
    values[17] = "1.0, 2.0, 4.0";
    double total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (String v : values[17].split(",")) {
        if (v != null) {
            total += Double.valueOf(v.trim());
            count++;
        }
    }
    double avg = total / ((double) count);
    System.out.println("The average of " + values[17] + " is " + avg);
}
```

Which outputs

```
The average of 1.0, 2.0, 4.0 is 2.3333333333333335
```

Answer (score 2):

If `values2[17]` is a String like "2 5 7", Then you need to parse all them each individually

```
String[] nums = valus2[17].split(" ");
double d1 = Double.parseDouble(num[0]);
double d2 = Double.parseDouble(num[1]);
double d3 = Double.parseDouble(num[3]);

double average = (d1 + d2 + d3) / 3;
```

On The other hand if you you have a String like "567" and you want the individual values, can you split into a char array then add the int values

```
String value = "567"     // value2[17]
char[] digits = value.toCharArray();

int total = 0;
for (char c : digits){
    total += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
}
double average = total / new Double(digits.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything with the i...

```
double total= 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
    total += values[i];
}
double avarage = total/3.0;
System.out.println(avarage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are adding the whole array to itself 3 times then dividing but you need to add the three ideas in the array then divide by three

do

```
double Avg = values2[0] + values2[1] + values2[2] / 3
```